# Search string in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to search a part of string like if a string saved is of name John Doe. and if i search for doe all people with name ending with doe comes

I'm using this right now

```
firebaseDatabase.child("Items").orderByChild("name").startAt(srch).endAt(srch+"\uf8ff")
```

i tried to put \uf8ff at start but it doesn't show anything.

please Help.

Comment: so you want the exact "John Doe"? it's not clear what you want exactly.

Comment: Firestore does not offer flexible substring searches.  You can search for string prefix by using the "\uf8ff" trick, but not string suffixes or anywhere else in the string.